# How do I create a proc_macro_attribute?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

Now that `proc_macros` [have been stabilized](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/52081), how does one create such a thing?

From what I've seen, there's the option of putting a `#[proc_macro_attribute]` annotation on a `fn whatsitsname(attrs: TokenStream, code: TokenStream) -> TokenStream`, but how can I register it? How can I add custom attributes?

Comment: For what it's worth, the book contains a [section on writing procedural macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/appendix-04-macros.html#procedural-macros-for-custom-derive).

Comment: @SvenMarnach this only explains `proc_macro_derive`, not `proc_macro_attribute`.

Comment: @llogiq I'm aware of that, however the link may be useful to other people landing here.  (And your first question is "how does one create such a thing", which is covered there.)

Comment: I would say that they should be documented in the Book appendix linked by @SvenMarnach and if they are not, it is a bug that should be reported *and* referenced in the tracking issue https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38356 (it is still open, and does not mention documenting the feature, but probably should).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Rust compiler has a fairly complete [test suite](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/master/src/test). When looking for examples of newly-introduced features, I frequently start there:

```
$ rg -c proc_macro_attribute
src/test/run-pass-fulldeps/auxiliary/proc_macro_def.rs:2
src/test/ui-fulldeps/auxiliary/attr_proc_macro.rs:1
[... 35 other matches ...]
```

Here's a fully worked example:

```
$ tree
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── my_macro
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   ├── src
│   │   └── lib.rs
└── src
    └── main.rs
```

**Cargo.toml**

We add a dependency on our macro-defining crate.

```ini
[package]
name = "foo"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["An Devloper <an.devloper@example.com>"]

[dependencies]
my_macro = { path = "my_macro" }
```

**src/main.rs**

We import the attribute macro and add it to a function.

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate my_macro;

#[log_entry_and_exit(hello, "world")]
fn this_will_be_destroyed() -> i32 {
    42
}

fn main() {
    dummy()
}
```

**my_macro/Cargo.toml**

We specify `crate_type` as `proc_macro`.

```ini
[package]
name = "my_macro"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["An Devloper <an.devloper@example.com>"]

[lib]
crate_type = ["proc-macro"]
```

**my_macro/src/lib.rs**

We add `#[proc_macro_attribute]` to each function that should be a macro.

```rust
extern crate proc_macro;

use proc_macro::*;

#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn log_entry_and_exit(args: TokenStream, input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let x = format!(r#"
        fn dummy() {{
            println!("entering");
            println!("args tokens: {{}}", {args});
            println!("input tokens: {{}}", {input});
            println!("exiting");
        }}
    "#,
            args = args.into_iter().count(),
            input = input.into_iter().count(),
    );

    x.parse().expect("Generated invalid tokens")
}
```

**cargo run**

```
entering
args tokens: 3
input tokens: 7
exiting
```

The "hard" part is wrangling the `TokenStream` into something useful and then outputting something equally useful. The crates [syn](https://crates.io/crates/syn) and [quote](https://crates.io/crates/quote) are the current gold standards for those two tasks. Dealing with `TokenStream` is covered in the [macros chapter of *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html) as well as [API documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.TokenStream.html).

There's also `#[proc_macro]`, which takes functions of the form:

```rust
#[proc_macro]
pub fn the_name_of_the_macro(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream
```

And can be invoked as `the_name_of_the_macro!(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand [RFC 1566](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1566-proc-macros.md) correctly, you:

- Create a crate of type `proc_macro`, i.e. its `Cargo.toml` should contain

```ini
[lib]
proc-macro = true
```

- In that crate, create the implementation, annotated with `#[proc_macro_attribute]`. The `#[proc_macro]` for function-like macros and `#[proc_macro_derive]` for custom derives work the same, except they only have one `TokenStream` argument. These are defined in the `proc_macro` crate.

  The first token stream is the arguments in the attribute, the second is the body of the annotated item.
- Then in the crate that wants to use the macro, simply depend on the proc_macro crate and
  import it with `#[macro_use]` attribute (`#[macro_use] extern crate` …).

That should be enough.

The [appendix in Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/appendix-04-macros.html#procedural-macros-for-custom-derive) should be extended to mention the other proc macro types beyond `#[proc_macro_derive]`. That it does not is probably a bug.