# How do I create a function-like procedural macro?

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

How should `a_proc_macro` be defined so it "returns" a 5?

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = a_proc_macro!();
    assert!(a == 5);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reading [The Rust Programming Language's](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) chapter on [macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html#function-like-macros) says:

> Function-like macros define macros that look like function calls. Similarly to
> `macro_rules!` macros, they’re more flexible than functions; for example, they
> can take an unknown number of arguments. However, `macro_rules!` macros can be
> defined only using the match-like syntax we discussed in the section
> [“Declarative Macros with `macro_rules!` for General Metaprogramming”](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html#declarative-macros-with-macro_rules-for-general-metaprogramming)
> earlier. Function-like macros take a `TokenStream` parameter and their
> definition manipulates that `TokenStream` using Rust code as the other two
> types of procedural macros do. An example of a function-like macro is an `sql!`
> macro that might be called like so:
>
> ```
> let sql = sql!(SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=1);
> ```
>
> This macro would parse the SQL statement inside it and check that it’s
> syntactically correct, which is much more complex processing than a
> `macro_rules!` macro can do. The `sql!` macro would be defined like this:
>
> ```
> #[proc_macro]
> pub fn sql(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
> ```
>
> This definition is similar to the custom derive macro’s signature: we receive
> the tokens that are inside the parentheses and return the code we wanted to
> generate.

---

Since [Rust 1.45](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1450-2020-07-16), you can invoke function-like procedural macros as an expression.

```
example
├── Cargo.toml
├── example-macro
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   ├── src
│   │   └── lib.rs
├── src
│   └── main.rs
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "example"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
example-macro = { path = "example-macro" }
```

**src/main.rs**

```
fn main() {
    assert_eq!(example_macro::a_proc_macro!(), 5);
}
```

**example-macro/Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "example-macro"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[lib]
proc-macro = true
```

**example-macro/src/lib.rs**

```
extern crate proc_macro;

use proc_macro::TokenStream;

#[proc_macro]
pub fn a_proc_macro(_input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    "5".parse().unwrap()
}
```

See also:

- [How do I create a proc_macro_attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52585719/155423)
- [Convert string into TokenStream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54165117/155423)
- [Why do proc-macros have to be defined in proc-macro crate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56713877/155423)
- [Tracking issue for procedural macros and "hygiene 2.0" (#54727)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54727)

Answer (score 1):

Directly defining expression-like procedural macros is not yet possible in stable Rust. If you can use nightly, [Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58922120/1600898) shows how.

If you are on stable, you can still emulate expression-like procedural macros as follows:

- define a procedural macro that expands to a function that evaluates to the expression you want to call;
- then define a regular macro that expands to a block that embeds the function definition and call.

In your case you'd define the procedural macro like this:

```
#[proc_macro]
pub fn a_proc_macro_impl(_input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    "fn output() -> usize { 5 }".parse().unwrap()
}
```

...the helper `macro_rules!` macro follows this pattern:

```
macro_rules! a_proc_macro {
    ($($t:tt)*) => {{
        struct _X;
        impl _X {
            a_proc_macro!($($t)*);
        }
        _X::output()
    }}
}
```

This is a hack, and a cumbersome one at that, but [proc-macro-hack](https://github.com/dtolnay/proc-macro-hack) crate comes to the rescue and makes it easier to generate procedural macros using the above technique. With the help of the `proc-macro-hack` crate, you can run the almost unchanged code from Shepmaster's answer on stable:

- edit both `Cargo.toml` files and add `proc-macro-hack = "0.5.11"` to the dependencies section;
- add `#[proc_macro_hack] use example_macro::a_proc_macro;` in `src/main.rs`, and invoke `a_proc_macro!` from the local namespace.
- add `#[proc_macro_hack::proc_macro_hack]` before the definition of `a_proc_macro` in `example-macro/src/lib.rs`.